# Bad request (400) in Postman with Graph API beta

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to execute a graph api request but it returns a bad request. It has all the permissions indicated in the official documentation and I don't see where it could be wrong in its syntax.
Get token:
[image]

The request failed:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using a service principal to authentication eg the client credentials flow so the /me endpoint isn't valid (which is what that error message is telling you). You need to target a specific user eg

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/profile
```

Comment: It's true! although now I get a 404, but that is another topic :)